# Android firebase java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get the following error in the next line of code

```
recentMessages = mDatabase.orderByKey().equalTo(obj).limitToLast(20);
```

The error is as follows

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference

This is the code

```
public class LikesFeedFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase ;
    private DatabaseReference mCommentsDatabase;
    private Query commentsQuery;
    Query recentMessages;
    private Query filterLike;
    private boolean mProcessLike = false;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
    private DatabaseReference ref;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        mCommentsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comentarios");
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        ref.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        mCommentsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String obj = objSnapshot.getKey().toString();

                    Log.e("Doo 3", obj);
                    recentMessages = mDatabase.orderByKey().equalTo(obj).limitToLast(20);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("Read failed", firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        mBlogList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.blog_list);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager =  new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        //linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mBlogList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FeedData,FeedViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FeedData, FeedViewHolder>(
            FeedData.class,
            R.layout.item_feed,
            FeedViewHolder.class,
            recentMessages) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder viewHolder, FeedData model, int position) {

                    final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                    viewHolder.setImage(getContext(), model.getThumb_image());
                    viewHolder.setLikeBtn(post_key);
                    commentsQuery = mCommentsDatabase.orderByChild("id_comment").equalTo(post_key);

                    commentsQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            long comentCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                            if (comentCount == 0) {
                                viewHolder.comments.setText("0 Comentarios");
                            }
                            else {
                                 viewHolder.comments.setText(String.valueOf(comentCount) + " Comentarios");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            long Count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (int) Count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("Doo", String.valueOf(Count));
                            if (Count == 0) {
                                viewHolder.likes.setText("0 likes");
                                // viewHolder.likes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            else {
                                 //viewHolder.likes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                viewHolder.likes.setText(String.valueOf(Count) + " likes");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder.imageBlog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intentBlog = new Intent(getActivity(), BlogSingleActivity.class);
                            intentBlog.putExtra("blog_id",post_key);

                            startActivity(intentBlog);
                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder.likeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void liked(final LikeButton likeButton) {
                            mProcessLike = true;

                            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (mProcessLike) {

                                    if (!dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {


                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("RandomValue");
                                        likeButton.setLiked(true);
                                        mProcessLike = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void unLiked(final LikeButton likeButton) {
                        mProcessLike = true;

                        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (mProcessLike) {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                                         mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                        likeButton.setLiked(false);
                                        mProcessLike = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
            }
        };

        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;
        LikeButton likeButton;
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        ImageView imageBlog;
        TextView likes;
        TextView comments;
        public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            likeButton = (LikeButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.heart_button);
            imageBlog = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageBlog);
            mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
            likes = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.count_like);
            comments = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comentCount);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        }

        public void setLikeBtn(final String post_key){

            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                        likeButton.setLiked(true);
                    }else{likeButton.setLiked(false);}
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }



        public void setTitle(String title){

            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);

        }

        public void setDesc(String desc){
            TextView desc_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            desc_title.setText(desc);

        }

        public void setImage(final Context ctx, final String image) {

            // Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(imageBlog);

            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.fondonav).into(imageBlog, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.fondonav).into(imageBlog);

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.add) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Crear publicacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class));
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a log-statement to `onStart()` to see if it runs before the `onDataChange()` (see below) that initializes `recentMessages` runs.  I suspect that it does, causing `recentMessages` to be null when it is passed into the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

I also question why you have the initialization of `recentMessages` in a for-loop.  And if the snapshot has no children, the loop doesn't run and `recentMessages` is not set.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        String obj = objSnapshot.getKey().toString();

        Log.e("Doo 3", obj);
        recentMessages = mDatabase.orderByKey().equalTo(obj).limitToLast(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the getKey () and then compare it in a Query and display the results in a recyclerview